# How can I get AWS secrets from Terraform into my docker container running Python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-fargate

I have a fargate instance, running Python(Flask) Docker containers. I was unable to read AWS secrets as I do from Lambda and my localhost. The system times out after 30 seconds and I have partly given up on that as a solution. (The problem is that my Python container cannot read AWS secrets manager) I do know however that I can import my AWS secrets into Terraform and I can see they are in Terraform.

How can I get those variables from Terraform into my docker container as a global variable? Is there anyway to inject them and then read them with, for instance, os.environ.get("zzz)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [aws_ecs_task_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition), when you specify `container_definitions`, you can provide [secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDefinition.html):

> The secrets to pass to the container. For more information, see Specifying Sensitive Data in the Amazon Elastic Container Service Developer Guide.

This allows you to:

> **inject** sensitive data into your containers by storing your sensitive data in either **AWS Secrets Manager secrets** or AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store parameters and then referencing them in your container definition.

Thus if you modify your `container_definitions` to use `secrets`, they will be automatically injected into your containers.